# MadiaStreamTrack zoom capability not returned in Android WebView but works on Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, mediastreamtrack

As shown in [this](https://web.dev/camera-pan-tilt-zoom/) article, calling `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` as follows should grant zoom permissions:

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ 
    video: { zoom: true }
});
```

Also, as stated in the same article:

> `MediaStreamTrack.getCapabilities()` *returns a dictionary with the supported capabilities and the ranges or allowed values. Correspondingly,* `MediaStreamTrack.getSettings()` *returns the current settings.*

With the information above I've done some testing in an Android device in both Chrome and in the Android WebView.
The tests were made using [this](https://ptz.glitch.me/) demo found in the same article.

Here are the results:

Chrome:

- [Detected version on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp9Eu.png)
- [Capabilities detected on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECD5I.png)
- [Settings detected on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Fd0.png)

WebView:

- [Detected version on webView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHuvG.png)
- [Capabilities detected on WebView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pet8P.png)
- [Settings detected on WebView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO9VW.png)

As you can see in the "Capabilities detected" and "Settings detected" images, in the WebView the zoom capability is not shown while it is shown in Chrome.

Have I done something wrong or is there a bug on the Android WebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it's a chromium issue and I don't think anyone is working on it

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1249435
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1137869